# Altium Text Font

Tags: pcb, altium

I have designed a board before and i wrote a text with a font type however i could not remember it. Do you remember the name of this Altium text font?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vladimir Script Regular - Windows 10 default installation.
Not an 'Altium' font, but a windows true type font.